# Ubuntu 16.04 failed upgrade

Tags: networking, upgrade

I have been using ubuntu 15.10. Yesterday i decided to upgrade to 16.04.
The software manager aborted saying upgrade failed because of too many errors.

Then i made the mistake of rebooting without fixing the install. Now it seems like i broke a lot of things.

1. Ubuntu is now not detecting my ethernet card at all. While booting there is a message, saying **cannot start raise network interfaces**. And then there is also a message saying. **eht0 no such device found**
2. Also there is a problem with the desktop, the menus and all window borders have completely dissappeared.

I mainly want a solution to the ethernet problem, without which i cannot access internet.

But an overall solution to fix everything would be perfect.

I have already tried :

```
dpgk --configure -a
apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

Is there a way i can fix only the broken packages, without having to erase and reinstall everything from scratch using a livecd?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from unstable release to LTS it's a bad idea. Use clean install. It prevents you from too many problems in a future.